# Como personalizar página principal de woocomerce en plantilla archive-produc.php

Tags: wordpress, plugin

recurro a ustedes héroes de la web porque tengo un problemilla que me ha dado ya un poco de dolor de cabeza, la situación es la siguiente:

Estoy haciendo un tema a la medida utilizando como plantilla base roots, la plantilla no del otro mundo, de hecho es muy simple, el problema es que me he dado a la tarea de incorporarle una tienda, para ello he utilizado el plugin Woocommerce, toda la configuración está correcta (como mencioné antes es muy simple la plantilla). El problema en el que me encuentro es que no logro la manera de configurar la tienda, es decir, la página principal de la tienda (la sección "tienda").

Se supone que el sitio tiene una sección llamada "tienda" que debe de visualizarse de la siguiente manera:

[image: Objetivo]

Pero la verdad es que el plugins trae automáticamente los posts más recientes y los lista en un solo contenedor :( de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve buscando y me encontré que para poder personalizar las plantillas de Wordpress, tengo que copiar las plantillas ubicadas en la carpeta del plugin a la carpeta de mi tema, así:

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates
wp-content/themes/mytema/woocommerce/templates

También leyendo la documentación de Woocomerce, mirando la prioridad de plantillas encontré que la plantilla que debo modificar es archive-product.php, sin embargo, no he podido hacer que woocomer me liste las categorías como yo quiero.

Si de algo sirve, acá está el código de esa plantilla.

```
<?php 
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    /*do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );*/
?>

    <?php /*if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif;*/?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>



        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    /*do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );*/
?><?php /*get_footer( 'shop' ); */?>
```

Comment: Entiendo que el plugin fue de paga ¿Qué plugin utilizaste?

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo woocommerce.php de tu tema puedes checkear en que página te encuentras y hacertelo customizado, tienes operadores como `is_product()`

Fuente: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, terminé haciendo uso de un plugin que me facilitó esta función pues el tiempo me consumía y tenía que entregar.